# Движение авто в 3d three.js не работает

Tags: javascript, анимация, 3d, three.js

Прошу извинить за грязнейший код - месяц только изучаю JS.
Очень хочу помощи по ключевым хотя бы моментам three.js и в целом. Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку drive: 1. При нажатии любой клавиши фиксируется множество нажатий (очень быстро все начинает тормозить, если зажать клавишу) 2. Движение на плоскости при нажатии кнопки drive должно быть от первого лица, вроде сделал, как в обучающих материалах, но работает совсем некорректно. Прилагаю ссылку на гитхаб: https://github.com/mrmadgav/rx8 в ридми ссылка на gitpages. Буду рад любым советам по коду/принципам построения таких вещей

```
// import {OrbitControls} from "./libs/three.min.js";
//Основные переменные

let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let car;
     
function init() {
  container = document.querySelector(".scene");

  //ДЕЛАЕМ СЦЕНУ
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const fov = 40;
  const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 2000;

  //ДЕЛАЕМ КАМЕРУ
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 50, 600);

  const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
  light.position.set(50, 50, 100);
  scene.add(light);

  //НАСТРОЙКИ ДЛЯ ДАТ ГУИ
  let settings = {
    // ключи поворота модели
    rotationX: -1.4,
    rotationY: 0,
    rotationZ: 0.0,
    // color: 0xff00ff,
    // lightPower: 5,
    // ключи цвета кузова
    bodyRed: 0.2,
    bodyGreen: 0.2,
    bodyBlue: 0.2,
    // ключи цвета дисков
    rimsRed: 0.2,
    rimsGreen: 0.2,
    rimsBlue: 0.2,
  };
  //Сам dat GUI

  let gui = new dat.GUI();
  // создаем ползунки вращения авто
  gui.add(settings, "rotationX").min(-1.5).max(1.5).step(0.001);
  gui.add(settings, "rotationY").min(-0.2).max(0.2).step(0.001);
  gui.add(settings, "rotationZ").min(-0.03).max(0.03).step(0.001);
  // папка с настроками цвета авто
  let guiBodyColors = gui.addFolder("Choose Body Color");
  guiBodyColors.add(settings, "bodyRed").min(0).max(0.7).step(0.005);
  guiBodyColors.add(settings, "bodyGreen").min(0).max(0.7).step(0.005);
  guiBodyColors.add(settings, "bodyBlue").min(0).max(0.7).step(0.005);
  guiBodyColors.open();
  //папка с настройками цвета дисков
  let guiRimsColors = gui.addFolder("Choose Rims Color");
  guiRimsColors.add(settings, "rimsRed").min(0).max(0.7).step(0.005);
  guiRimsColors.add(settings, "rimsGreen").min(0).max(0.7).step(0.005);
  guiRimsColors.add(settings, "rimsBlue").min(0).max(0.7).step(0.005);
  guiRimsColors.open();
  // gui.add(settings, "lightPower").min(0).max(10).step(0.5); - найти динамическое изменение света на модели

  // ДЕЛАЕМ РЕНДЕР
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // кнопка переключения анимации
  let drive = document.querySelector("button");
  drive.dataset.status = "OnStyle";
  // console.log(drive.dataset.status === 'OnStyle');

  function animate() {
    // если кнопка Drive не нажата, то анимируем объект в режиме стилизации
    if (drive.dataset.status === "OnStyle") {
      // поворот модели
      car.rotation.x = settings.rotationX;
      car.rotation.y = settings.rotationY;
      car.rotation.z += settings.rotationZ;
      // цвет кузова
      let bodyIDcolor =
        car.parent.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].material
          .color;
      bodyIDcolor.r = settings.bodyRed;
      bodyIDcolor.g = settings.bodyGreen;
      bodyIDcolor.b = settings.bodyBlue;
      // цвет дисков
      let rimIDcolor =
        car.parent.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[11].material
          .color;
      rimIDcolor.r = settings.rimsRed;
      rimIDcolor.g = settings.rimsGreen;
      rimIDcolor.b = settings.rimsBlue;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    // по нажатию кнопки объект с выбранными настройками цвета и т.д должен получить возможность ехать в режиме "Chase Cam" по небольшому треку или типа того. По нажатию "esс" - возврат в режим стилизации
    if (drive.dataset.status === "OnDrive") {
      document.body.style.background = "none";
      gui.close();

      let ground = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500);
      let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial((wireframe = true));

      meshGround = new THREE.Mesh(ground, material);

      scene.add(meshGround);
      meshGround.rotation.x += Math.PI / 2;
      let gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(800, 50);
      scene.add(gridHelper);
      let axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(500);
      scene.add(axesHelper);

      car.rotation.x = -1.57;
      // let carSets = { turnSpeed: Math.PI * 0.02, accSpeed: 0 }; - настройки будущего движущегося объекта car
      //отлавливает нажатие клавиши управления
      document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keydown", logKey);

      // эта функция возвращает множество нажатий клавиши в текущем формате кода, хотя сама по себе работает правильно
      function logKey(e) {
        console.log(`${e.code}`);
        // W move
        if (e.code === "KeyW") {
          console.log("pressed W");
          camera.position.x -= Math.sin(camera.rotation.y);
          camera.position.z -= -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y);
          car.position.set(
            camera.position.x + Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * 0,
            6,
            camera.position.y - 0.5,
            camera.position.z + Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * 0.6
          );
        }
        // S move
        if (e.code === "KeyS") {
          camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y);
          camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y);
          car.position.set(
            camera.position.x - Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * 0,
            6,
            camera.position.y - 0.5,
            camera.position.z + Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * 0.6
          );
        }
        // A move Turn Left
        if (e.code === "KeyA") {
          camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2);
          camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2);
          // car.rotation.set( - авто переворачивается
          //   camera.rotation.x,
          //   camera.rotation.y - Math.PI,
          //   camera.rotation.z
          // );
        }
        if (e.code === "KeyD") {
          camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI / 2);
          camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI / 2);
          // car.rotation.set(
          //   camera.rotation.x,
          //   camera.rotation.y - Math.PI,
          //   camera.rotation.z
          // );
        }
        // вид от первого лица
        // car.position.set(
        //   camera.position.x - Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * 0,
        //   6,
        //   camera.position.y - 0.5,
        //   camera.position.z + Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * 0.6
        // );
        // car.rotation.set(
        //   camera.rotation.x,
        //   camera.rotation.y - Math.PI,
        //   camera.rotation.z
        // );
        // dVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        // camera.lookAt(dVector);
      }
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }

  // Orbit Controls
  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  //ЗАГРУЗЧИК МОДЕЛИ
  let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load("./mazda_rx8/sceneUpdated.gltf", function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    car = gltf.scene.children[0];
    // console.log(car.children[0].children[0].children[19].geometry.boundingSphere.radius); попытка достучаться до радиуса колеса
    // console.log(car.parent.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[11].material);

    // Функция, включающая по нажатию на кнопку drive камеру от первого лица и возможность ездить на авто

    let makeDrive = () => {
      drive.dataset.status = "OnDrive";
    };
    drive.addEventListener("click", makeDrive);

    // -------- //

    controls.update();
    animate(); // функция запускает анимацию
  });
}

init(); // запускаем всю сцену

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

Comment: Даже не понятно - с какой стороны подступиться. Для начала - вынести строку `document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keydown", logKey);` и функцию `logKey()` из цикла анимации. Ибо из-за того, что на каждую итерацию к body добавляется новый обработчик события - в логе получается столько записей при нажатии. Затем из цикла анимации вынести создание и добавление в сцену meshGround и gridHelper (создавать и добавлять их надо до запуска цикла анимации). И наконец `renderer.render(scene, camera);  requestAnimationFrame(animate);` вынести из блоков `if`, оставив один в конце `animate()`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Убрал из анимации document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keydown", logKey); - теперь клавиши корректно работают, а вот с остальным пока не выходит - выкидывает ошибку "dom element undefined" и не отрисовывает meshGround и gridHelper, буду пытаться поправить